# Error al validar login Usuario y contraseña Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Quiero hacer un login sencillo en Android Studio el cual al validar los datos me lleve a otro activity, para eso cree la clase Usuarios

```
public class Usuarios {
    private String usuario = "Pepe";
    private int contrasena = 11223344;

    public Usuarios() {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public int getContrasena() {
        return contrasena;
    }

    public void setContrasena(int contrasena) {
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }
}
```

Codigo de mi activity

```
import Objetos.Usuarios;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText usuario, contrasena;
    private Button sesion, calcular;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idusuario);
        contrasena = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idcontrasena);
        sesion = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSesion);
        calcular = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalculos);
    }

    public void Start(View view) {
        Usuarios user = new Usuarios();

        if(usuario = user.getUsuario().toString().equals("Pepe") && contrasena = user.getContrasena()){
    
        if(sesion.isClickable()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Dulces_act.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    public void Calcular(View view) {
        if (calcular.isClickable()) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, CalcularDulces_act.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero me tira error mi codigo, no logro que la condicional me funcione.
¿como tendría que hacerlo para que lo que escriba el usuario lo pueda validar con el dato usuario "pepe" y la contraseña 11223344 y poder entrar al otro activity?

Comment: No entiendo por que en haces esta comparación: user.getUsuario().toString().equals("Joao") y luego le asignas el resultado a EditText de usuario. ¿Qué error te está dando exactamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clase Usuarios ya tiene 2 valores definidos y aquí puedes definir los valores que deseas comparar

```
private String usuario = "Pepe";
 private int contrasena = 11223344;
```

Por lo tanto la comparación para abrir tu Activity debería ser:

```
public void Start(View view)
{
    Usuarios user = new Usuarios();

    if(usuario.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(user.getUsuario()) && Integer.parseInt(contrasena.getText().toString()) == user.getContrasena()){
    
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Dulces_act.class);
            startActivity(i);  

    }
}
```

---

Es importante tengas las siguientes  consideraciones:

Para obtener el texto definido en un EditText debes usar:

```
getText().toString()
```

Para convertir una cadena a entero puedes usar:

```
Integer.parseInt(...)
```

Para comparar un entero debes usar el operador:

```
==
```

Para comparar dos cadenas y ver si son iguales ignorando las diferencias entre mayúsculas y minúsculas se usa:

```
equalsIgnoreCase(...)
```